# How to register an interface for interceptions

Tags: castle-windsor

I want to register an interface like: `IInterceptingAware`, so that for all classes which implement this interface an interceptor class is used.

```
public class InterceptorClass : IInterceptor
{
 public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
 {
     // Do my work
 }
}

public class Foo : IInterceptingAware
{
}

public class Bar : IInterceptingAware
{
}
```

How do I setup castle windsor for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<MyInterceptorClass>(),
        Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IInterceptingAware>()
            .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
            .ConfigureFor<IInterceptingAware>(c => c.Interceptors<MyInterceptorClass>())
        );

    var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
    foo.Test();

    var bar = container.Resolve<IBar>();
    bar.Test();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Keep in mind interceptor requires at least virtual methods on target class, even better your target class should implement an interface in order to have the interceptor working on that contract.

Said so, your `Foo` class should at least have a method named `Test` marked as `virtual`
while `Bar` should implement `IBar`:

```
public interface IBar
{
    void Test();
}
```